# How to code a time count down in JSP?

Tags: jsp, timer

How can I implement a time counter in JSP page, when click start it will counting down, when time up pop out a message?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) javascript function:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // 5 seconds after the page is loaded show an alert:
    alert('5 seconds have passed since the page was loaded');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I want it start when user click on the button

Comment: Well, then execute this function when the button is clicked (onclick).

Comment: Any other method, if I want to set the time dynamically, it is for online test, so different test got different duration.

Comment: You could use server side tags to set the interval.

Comment: once the page refresh it will restart the count, any idea let it continue ?